# Effectively check if a polynomial has a root in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, p-adic-number-theory

I'm looking for an algorithm that, given as input a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and a prime number $p$, returns as output $\max_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} v_p(f(n))$ (which belongs to $\mathbb{N} \cup \{+\infty\}$), where $v_p(\cdot)$ is the $p$-adic valuation. In particular, note that the output is $+\infty$ if and only if $f$ has a root in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so this algorithm would also be an effective method to check if a polynomial has a root in the $p$-adic integers.

I know the Hensel's lemma in the form: *"If $x_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is such that $2v_p(f^\prime(x_0)) < v_p(f(x_0))$ then there exists a unique $\widetilde{x}_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(\widetilde{x}_0) = 0$ and $\widetilde{x}_0 \equiv x_0 \bmod p^{v_p(f^\prime(x_0)) + 1}$."* but I have not been able to build such algorithm using it, so I guess other results are needed.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Check out Strassman's theorem, that might help. It gives an upper bound on the number of p-adic integer roots of a power series based on the last term with the largest absolute value. For instance, $f(x)=1+px+x^2+px^3+px^4$ has at most 2 p-adic integer roots because $|a_2|_p=1$ is the last largest term.

Comment: I imagine that *Newton polygons* can be very helpful for this. Have a look at http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/number_theory/newton_polygon.pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon, with further references therein.